# How to efficiently iterate over nested arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript project where I need to iterate over a nested array structure!? Each nested array can contain multiple levels of sub-arrays, and I need to perform some operations on the elements at each level?

Currently, I'm using nested for loops to iterate over the arrays, but I feel like this approach is not very efficient and could be improved... I've heard about higher-order functions like map, reduce, and forEach, but I'm not sure how to utilize them effectively for this nested array scenario.

Could someone please guide me on the most efficient and concise way to iterate over nested arrays in JavaScript? Is there a specific higher-order function or a combination of functions that would be suitable for this task? Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!?

yes, I have tried some tutorials

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `map`, `reduce` and `forEach`? What's your expected end product after iterating?

Comment: sample data and code that you've tried would help

Comment: @Portal I've using multilevel bitcoin chain, sorry, but I cannot share my source code with you, if you think that is nothing to do, but in fact it's not

Comment: @Portal why did you close my answer?

Comment: @aoa I didn't, I don't have the power to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flatten it (array.flat(depthLevel)) and loop over that result.

Post your code it'll be easier to answer next time.